# PHP Zend 1 Date translations not translating correctly for Finnish

Tags: php, zend-framework, translation

I'm working on a fairly old project, built on the Zend 1 framework.

There's an issue with translation, specifically Finnish.

To test, I'm running the following code:

```
(new Zend_Date(time(), false, new Zend_Locale($locale)))->toString(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL);
```

Assigning $locale the following values give the following results, respectively:

- English: 'en' results in 'Monday, August 21, 2023'
- Finnish: 'fi'
  results in 'cccc 21. elokuuta 2023'
- Danish: 'da' results in 'mandag
  den 21. august 2023'
- Norwegian: 'nb' results in 'mandag 21. august
  2023'

The correct translation for the Finnish string is 'maanantai 21. elokuuta 2023', but for some reason it's outputting 'cccc' instead of the correct string. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: I don't understand where the hostility is coming from - I've already tried searching extensively online to try to find out what could be wrong, stackoverflow isn't my first port of call, I come here once I feel like I've done what I can to find out what could be wrong. Not sure what you want me to try, the line of code I showed is what I want to use, and it works for 21 other languages including the ones mentioned in my post.

Comment: No hostility, it was just unclear what you're asking for. Do you require a replacement (as suggest per acceptance of the answer below) or are you looking to patch ZF1. Just showing the error picture does not tell that. That's what I meant by elaborate. And IIRC there is a script in ZF1 to generate the underlying XML files to update them from ICU and/or similar sources. Not trying to blame you here for using ZF1 even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend Framework has been long-since abandoned. [Your exact question appears in their archived GitHub issues from nearly a decade ago](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/562). The answer: it's old, there are numerous issues, and nobody is going to update the translation & internationalization files at this point.

Luckily, that line of code can easily be updated to use the INTL extension (which wraps ICU's C library) and will deliver the correct output via the [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class:

```php
echo (new IntlDateFormatter($locale, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE))->format(time());
```

[Live example on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/918e6#v8.2.9).

Comment: Note that if you're running a version of PHP that is just as old as Zend 1, this may not work if the INTL library's timezone database it too out-of-date, but if you're using a more modern version of PHP, the output should work fine.